# Run nmcli as unprivileged user

Tags: permissions, network-manager, raspberrypi, dbus

I wrote a Python program to switch WiFi connections via the Network Manager dbus interface, which (I believe) is basically equivalent to the nmcli command-line tool. The script (and nmcli) work properly when run by an unprivileged user on my desktop Ubuntu. I'm trying to figure out how the permissions to allow that were set up.

I'm asking because the same commands don't work on Raspbian, so I'd like to track down where the permissions are different. On Raspbian, when I run my script as an unprivileged user, I get this error when I try to read NetworkManager data via dbus:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Settings.PermissionDenied: No session found for uid 1000 (unknown)
```

and, equivalently, when I run `nmcli c` as an unprivileged user on Raspbian, it doesn't show the connections as it should. Both work properly with `sudo`.

### My attempts so far

I found some old Ubuntu posts that suggest the PolicyKit package is involved, and that I should create a file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pkla` with these contents:

```
[Enable NetworkManager]
Identity=unix-group:netdev
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.*
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

That didn't change anything though. (Notes: all other `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority` subfolders are empty, and the user is part of the netdev group. I'm not sure what else to check.)

I'm very new to dbus and NetworkManager, so I'd appreciate any help understanding how the permissions to send dbus signals are granted, and how I can troubleshoot a missing NetworkManager permission.

Comment: The polkit fill you created, did it have the pkla extension?

Comment: `No session found for uid 1000` sounds like something more fundamental than a permissions issue - how exactly are you executing the script, in particular is there a running desktop session with a valid DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS for the invoking user?

Comment: logind is responsible for managing the sessions that network manager is complaining about. Perhaps check that the service is running. Try running loginctl to see if it lists any sessions.

Comment: Thanks guys; the file does have the pkla extension (just edited my question to add that). bwduncan and steeldriver , I think you guys might be on to something. I've been running the script via SSH or with supervisord at startup (the system is for a robot so it doesn't have a graphical desktop installed). ```loginctl``` says '0 sessions listed'. Does that prevent policykit from working? If so, is there a workaround?

Comment: Also, ```ps aux``` shows that ```/lib/systemd/systemd-logind``` is running as root. There are definitely no systemd user sessions though. I'm having trouble figuring out how to add one, as all docs I can find just say that they should exist.

Comment: I ended up writing a separate daemon that runs as root, just for nmcli. I'm not happy about it but it works at least. If any hero comes across this thread in the future, I'd still love to know if this is solvable.

Answer (score 0):

"No session found for uid 1000" being solved by reinstalling dbus package.

```
apt install dbus
```

then it's important to reboot, as dbus configs gets upgraded only after.